# $\tan( x + i y ) = a + ib$ then $\tan (x - iy) = a - ib $?

Tags: trigonometry

How to prove, if $\tan( x + i y ) = a + ib$ then $\tan (x - iy) = a - ib $ ?

I am not familiar with trignometric identities. So any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: tan⁡(x+iy)=(tan⁡x+tan⁡iy)/(1-tan⁡x  tan⁡iy ) and tan⁡(-iy)=-tan⁡iy

Comment: @NilanC.Manoj I have used this identity first. I cant able to simplify and get the solution. any more hints please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $$\tan z={e^{iz}-e^{-iz}\over e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}=1-{2\over 1+e^{-2iz}}$$

From there it follows immediately from

$$\overline{1\over w}={1\over\bar{w}}$$

You're trying to show that by taking complex conjugates **inside** the tangent you get the same result as if you put it **outside**.

So look at the formula, what is $\tan(\bar{z})$? well, it's:

$$\overline{tan(z)}=\overline{1-{2\over 1+e^{-2i(x+iy)}}}=1-{2\over 1+e^{2y+2ix}}=1-{2\over 1+e^{2i(x-iy)}}=\tan(\bar{z})$$

Comment: can you explain your answer little bit more. I cant see the solution clearly. Thanks.

Comment: @GA316 I've added details

Comment: nice answer. Thanks a lot.