# Having trouble solving a problem involving hyperbolic trignometric functions

Tags: complex-numbers, hyperbolic-functions

We have to find the value of
 $$ \tanh^{2}a * \cosh^{2} b - \cos^ {2} c \, $$

if $$\sin(a+ib) * \sin(c+id) = 1.$$

Can anyone solve this? Pls share the solution

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\sin(a+ib)\cdot\sin(c+id)=1\implies\sin(a-ib)\cdot\sin(c-id)=1$$

$$\sin(a+ib)\cdot\sin(a-ib)=\sin^2a-\sin^2(ib)=\sin^2a-(i\sinh b)^2$$

and use $\cosh^2u-\sinh^2u=1$

Alternatively, 
$$\sin(a+ib)=\sin a\cos(ib)+\cos a\sin(ib)=\sin(a)\cosh(b)+i\cos(a)\sinh(b)$$

Comment: i didn't get the first part clear

Comment: @user3464111, If $$f(x+iy)=a+ib$$ where $a,b$ are real, $$f(x-iy)=a-ib$$  Like  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860947/tan-x-i-y-a-ib-then-tan-x-iy-a-ib

Comment: ok. thanks for that. Here you have taken sin (a+ib) . sin (a-ib). Should i also consider sin(c+id). sin(c-id) ??

Comment: @user3464111, Of course and proceed

Comment: can you give the solution for this? am getting stuck at many parts :(

Comment: @user3464111, Please share your steps. You can apply modulus at both sides as well

Comment: i haven't made a fair draft. It's all rough now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27562/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-user3464111).